# omnidb behind envoy proxy

Tags: sql, envoyproxy

I'm trying to setup an [omnidb](https://omnidb.org/) server behind a [envoy proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/)

It was working fine with Nginx but I had to change to envoy for some reason...

I'm using omnidb v2.17

The issue is with the [websocket omnidb](https://omnidb.readthedocs.io/en/2.17.0/en/19_deploying_omnidb-server.html?highlight=nginx#deploying-omnidb-behind-a-reverse-proxy) is using. I can connect fine to omnidb, I can loggin but when I run SQL query, I get the following error:

> cannot connect to websocket server with ports 443 (external) and 26000 (internal)

When I inspect in the browser I see the following error in the console:
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-domain.com/wss' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

After few second I have this error in the console:
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-domain.com:26000/wss' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

EDIT: In envoy log I have this:
`[2021-02-16T18:52:19.016Z] "GET /wss HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0 77 63 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" "0d9be0f1-9517-43e0-8a66-355804dd23c7" "my-domain.com" "10.0.0.1:8080"`
So it seems it try to forward to "10.0.0.1:8080" instead of port 26000. Is it that the prefix "/" match before "/wss" so everything goes to port 8080 ?

Here is my `envoy.yaml` file:

```
static_resources:

  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 443
    filter_chains:
    - filter_chain_match:
        server_names:
        - my-domain.com
      filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http_and_wss
          upgrade_configs:
          - upgrade_type: websocket
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
              path: /dev/stdout
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
          route_config:
            name: omnidb
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/wss/"
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: omnidb_ws
              - match:
                  prefix: "/ws/"
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: omnidb_ws
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: omnidb
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
              certificate_chain:
                filename: /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/cert.pem
              private_key:
                filename: /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem


  clusters:
  - name: omnidb
    connect_timeout: 30s
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: omnidb
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 10.0.0.1
                port_value: 8080
  - name: omnidb_ws
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: omnidb_ws
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 10.0.0.1
                port_value: 26000
```

PS: I can't create the tag `omnidb` so I put `SQL` instead, would be nice to have a tag omnidb

Comment: yes, try just re-ordering the two route matches.  If you do it with prefix paths, "/" needs to go very last or it will match everything.  Envoy attempts the route matches from top to bottom, and uses the first one that matches.

Comment: I tried but it still the same. I updated in my message the envoy.yaml file. Still have the same error. I don't understand why it tries to connect to 'wss://my-domain.com:26000/wss' instead of 'wss://10.0.0.1:26000'

Answer (score 2):

After the edit above to get the `/` route as the last, otherwise it will match everything, now you need to fix how you send your request or how you treat the two routes in regard to trailing slashes.

The main point here:

- You have route matches for `/wss/` and `/ws/`, both with trailing slashes
- You send a request with `/wss` with *NO* trailing slash.
- This request matches neither of the two first routes, so it gets to the `/` route again.

You can send your request with `/wss/` *(note the trailing slash)* or you can add/modify your routes.  This can be done a number of ways, the simplest would probably be to just match on `/wss` and `/ws`.  *though if the trailing slash is important to the end application (which it can be in UIs), you can have `/wss` redirect to `/wss/`*

I tested this just slight modifications to your config.  Ignore the changes in the filter chains, the only thing that matters is the routes.

```yaml
static_resources:

  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8443
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http_and_wss
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
              path: /dev/stdout
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
          route_config:
            name: omnidb
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/wss"
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: omnidb_ws
              - match:
                  prefix: "/ws"
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: omnidb_ws
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: omnidb


  clusters:
  - name: omnidb
    connect_timeout: 30s
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: omnidb
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 10.0.0.1
                port_value: 8080
  - name: omnidb_ws
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: omnidb_ws
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 10.0.0.1
                port_value: 26000
```

Then `curl localhost:8443/wss` or `curl localhost:8443/wss/` show they get to your 26000 address.

```sh
[2021-02-22T15:57:22.818Z] "GET /wss/ HTTP/1.1" 503 UF 0 91 3 - "-" "curl/7.68.0" "806c2c28-4ab4-4069-acf1-15b75405d390" "localhost:8443" "10.0.0.1:26000"
[2021-02-22T15:57:27.287Z] "GET /wss HTTP/1.1" 503 UF 0 91 3 - "-" "curl/7.68.0" "55d32a64-c9f7-46cc-8f5e-4a024c0de00d" "localhost:8443" "10.0.0.1:26000"
```

Comment: Thx for your help! The `/wss` instead of `/wss/` makes sense :) I tried but it still not working. However the redirect seems to work as in the envoy log I saw 10.0.0.1:26000, so it might be something else... Anyway I will probably migrate to omnidb v3 which from what I saw doesn't websocket anymore

Comment: no problem, glad I could help.  Just to confirm though, you used the route rules from above, not the entire config right?  I modified some other things for my local setup, which would break what you need.

Comment: Yes I used just the route, I will give it another try when I have time

Comment: @justincely How would one do to force a trailing slash rewrite on all routes?

Comment: sry - didn't notice this.  I'd say you could probably do that with the regex_match and regex_rewrite.  Never tried, but i would think that would work.